# How do i call a view from within a view in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

hi this is my controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('frontend/menu/main_menu_view'); 
        $this->load->view('frontend/header/header_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/home/index_view');
    }
```

and this is the code from the index_view view :

```
echo $menu;
```

but is not working, what should I do ? thx

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of `$this->load->view()` doesn't load the view but returns it as 'data', to do with it what you please, muwahhahah! Sorry.

```
$data['menu'] = $this->load->view('frontend/menu/main_menu_view' , '', true);
```

You can still pass `$data` into that view.

So from inside of

```
$this->load->view('frontend/header/header_view',$data);
```

you will echo `$menu`

Scroll to the bottom of the [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Comment: This would be the best practice, you might want to create or utilize a [template class](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template)

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
$this->load->view('frontend/menu/main_menu_view');
```

from inside any view file and it will load and display for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, you have to write just this :

```
<?php 
$this->view('frontend/menu/main_menu_view');
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if you copied this from your code
or made a typo while typing your question, here, but shouldn't it be

`echo $menu;`

instead of

`echo menu;`
?

edit: Also, haven't worked with Codeigniter in a while,
but why pass $data to the header_view and call it from the index_view instead ?

Comment: it is not from there :) I forgot to write the $.

Comment: I edited my answer. There is that other thing, why not try calling the data['menu'] from the view you attached it to?

Comment: it does not matter where i want to pass the variable, neither way is not working! and the echo $menu line, I didn;t want to copy paste from my code , because it was to short and i wrote it by hand :)

Comment: please if you have any ideea why is not working, im opened minded, thx :D